# How do you test alternate branch of a return gaurd with jest?

Tags: node.js, typescript, jestjs

Jest is telling me I have only tested 50% of the branches of my return tested. How do I test alternate branches?

```
const getClient = (): Collection => {
  return collection(process.env.DB_COLLECTION || "Null");
};
```

I have tested that when I call getClient I get a collection handler. But code coverage only has 50% for the branching on the return

Comment: Has the `|| "Null"` branch been covered?

Comment: I thought it had, but upon double checking that is the issue. So obvious looking at it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could change the `value` of `process.env.DB_COLLECTION` environment variable for test case.

E.g.

`index.ts`:

```js
import { collection } from './collection';

type Collection = any;

export const getClient = (): Collection => {
  return collection(process.env.DB_COLLECTION || 'Null');
};
```

`collection.ts`:

```js
export function collection(name: string) {
  return 'real implementation';
}
```

`index.test.ts`:

```js
import { getClient } from './';
import { collection } from './collection';

jest.mock('./collection');

describe('64811936', () => {
  it('should pass 1', () => {
    getClient();
    expect(collection).toBeCalledWith('Null');
  });

  it('should pass 2', () => {
    const DB_COLLECTION = process.env.DB_COLLECTION;
    process.env.DB_COLLECTION = 'test';
    getClient();
    expect(collection).toBeCalledWith('test');
    process.env.DB_COLLECTION = DB_COLLECTION;
  });
});
```

unit test result:

```
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/64811936/index.test.ts
  64811936
    ✓ should pass 1 (6ms)
    ✓ should pass 2 (1ms)

---------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File           |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
---------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files      |       80 |      100 |       50 |       80 |                   |
 collection.ts |       50 |      100 |        0 |       50 |                 2 |
 index.ts      |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
---------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       2 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        3.687s, estimated 13s
```